# Is there another way to intercept "Up" button in the action bar other than catching the "android.R.id.home" case onOptionsItemSelected()?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation

The question is pretty self-explanatory, I reckon, but let me provide some more details.

I want to intercept the Up navigation button and show a dialog to the user (for accidental cases), but I do not want to do it in onOptionsItemSelected(). Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

this may help you.

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add your own ImageButton, with the 'Up' icon set, to the Toolbar and then set an onClick listener that simple shows a dialog and some clicked variable that way if it gets clicked again you finish the activity.